# Why do I get an exception when trying to append a block to a container in a parent theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme

I'm following an exercise in the ebook 'No-Frills-Magento-2-Layout' by Alan Storm (excellent book so far btw) and am coming across a slight issue for which I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a new theme with the intention of adding a new block to the `catalog_category_view` layout template.

I have the following code structure:

```
/design
    /frontend
        /Pulsestorm
            /dram
                /Magento_Catalog
                    registration.php
                    theme.xml
                    /layout
                        catalog_category_view.xml
                    /templates
                        hello.phtml
```

The files contents are as follows:

**registration.php:**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Pulsestorm/dram',
    __DIR__
);
```

**theme.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Pulsestorm Dram</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image/>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**catalog_category_view.xml:**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="pulsestorm_magento_catalog_category_view_example" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="hello.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**hello.phtml:**

```
<h2>Hello Category Listing Page</h2>
```

I then registered the theme in admin in `Content -> Design -> Themes` for each website listed (the default websites that ship with Magento 2).

I then cleared the cache: `magento cache:clean`

and then navigated to: `[development-web-address]/gear/fitness-equipment.html`

but I then get the following exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'hello.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'pulsestorm_magento_catalog_category_view_example'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'hello.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'pulsestorm_magento_catalog_category_view_example'
#0 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('pulsestorm_mage...')
...
```

I am expecting `<h2>Hello Category Listing Page</h2>` to be displayed after the product listings.  Why am I getting this exception?  From the exception message, I'm guessing that it may have something to do with the blank module name but I'm not sure why it is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Your theme architecture should be like this:

```
--app/design/frontend/Pulsestorm/dram/
                                     |__ Magento_Catalog/
                                                        |__ layout
                                                        |__ templates
                                     |__ registration.php
                                     |__ theme.xml
```

2- So the `registration.php` `theme.xml` must be inside : `app/design/frontend/Pulsestorm/dram/` and not inside `Magento_Catalog`.

3- `app/design/frontend/Pulsestorm/dram/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pulsestorm_magento_catalog_category_view_example"  template="Magento_Catalog::hello.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3- `app/design/frontend/Pulsestorm/dram/Magento_Catalog/templates/hello.phtml`

```
<h2>Yehoo, it works !<h2>
```

If you didn't notice it , I add `Magento_Catalog::` in **xml** part `template="Magento_Catalog::hello.phtml"/>` and **why** ?

**Explanation:**

When you declared you **phtml** in **xml**, you tel to Magento, please Magento render my `hello.phtml`, ok so Magento go to get it from your theme `Magento_Theme` => `app/design/frontend/Pulsestorm/dram/Magento_Theme` and it didn't find it ! but now by adding  `Magento_Catalog`, Magento know now that you want to get your file from `Magento_Catalog`, so it goes to get it from there.

Good luck.

Comment: It seems that I'd made a few mistakes here.  Thank you for your answer and for the useful explanation.  Very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome :) good luck